# Spatial polygon dataset + subset

Tags: r

I'm working with a spatial polygon dataframe.
data can be downloaded here:
http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/lower-layer-super-output-areas-december-2011-super-generalised-clipped-boundaries-in-england-and-wales

This contains the lower layer output area (lsoa) for England and Wales.

I need to subset the dataframe in order to keep only the polygons for the london lsoa11cd.

I have a list of lsoa11cd for London. 
These are between E01000001 and E01004765. I'm not sure how to proceed to subset the spatial polygons (see image attached). Find below an attempt which does not work.

```
london <- shapefile[substr(shapefile@data$lsoa11cd, -7 , -1) <= 1004765, ]
london <- london[substr(london@data$lsoa11cd, -7 , -1) >= 1000001, ]
```

[image: Dataframe screenshot]

Comment: `substr` doesn't work with negative start and stop (not `base::substr`, at least). Try `substr(..., 2, 8)` instead. And the result will be a string, convert to numeric before comparing to a number.

Comment: In general, I would recommend the debugging strategy of trying small test cases before posting here. I just did `x = "E01000001"` and then `substr(x, -7, -1)`. It didn't work. Then when I got `substr(x, 2, 8)`, I tried `substr(x, 2, 8) > 1`, which also didn't work, so I got to `as.integer(substr(x, 2, 8)) > 1`, which works as expected.

Comment: I tried. I used as.numeric(substr(shapefile, 2,8)) <= 1004765 but it does not subset. Also, as.integer does not work.

Comment: You still need the `shapefile@data$lsoa11cd` as in your question, not just `shapefile`. And try just subsetting the `@data`, not the other stuff. If you post a *minimal* bit of data, we can share code.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. You very kind. Data can be downloaded here: http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/lower-layer-super-output-areas-december-2011-super-generalised-clipped-boundaries-in-england-and-wales You need to download the file and use readOGR to import the shapefile into R

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpretting your question correctly, this should work nicely:

Use the `shapefile` function from the `raster` package to read-in the shapefile:

```
library(raster)

# Read-in the data. This will create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with 34,753 features
s <- shapefile('Lower_Layer_Super_Output_Areas_December_2011_Super_Generalised_Clipped__Boundaries_in_England_and_Wales.shp')
```

It looks like all of the `lsoa11cd` values have a letter and a number as the first two characters in the string. Let's first subset the data to keep only those with 'E' as the first chatacter for their `lsoa11cd` value.

```
s <- s[grep("^[aE].*", s$lsoa11cd), ]
```

Now we can remove the first two characters from each `lsoa11cd` string and convert to a numeric variable for easier subsetting as follows:

```
s$lsoa11cd <- as.numeric(substring(s$lsoa11cd, 3))
```

Then you can simply subset within the range you've specified:

```
s <- s[s$lsoa11cd %in% 1000001:1004765, ]
```

Comment: Perhaps more direct: `s <- s[s$lsoa11cd %in% paste0("E0", 1000001:1004765), ]`